# Python regex: Matching one named group or another

Tags: python, regex

I hav a string, that can contain the following:

```
lots of text Nov 30  2011 lots more of text
```

or

```
lots of text Nov 30 12:48 lots more of text
```

What I want to match is the date inside that line. What I want to get is the following for the first line:

```
{'date': 'Nov 30  2011', 'time': None}
```

or for the second line:

```
{'date': None, 'time': 'Nov 30 12:48'}
```

So my attemp was to this:

```
re.match(
    '^.+((?P<date>\w{3} \d{1,2}  \d{4})|(?P<time>\w{3} \d{1,2}:\d{2})).+', 
    line
)
```

But this does not work, it returns `None`. I tried some other combinations, but none worked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the day on the `<time>` group (e.g. *"Nov 12:48"*):

```
(?P<date>\w{3} \d{1,2}  \d{4})|(?P<time>\w{3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{2})
```

Also, you can probably match for that pattern without the `^.+(...).+` - it doesn't add much beyond requiring at least on character before and after your date.
I'd also recommend replacing spaces with `\s+` or `+` (space plus, or `[ ]+` if you want it visible) - you have double spaces in some places, which isn't too robust.

Another option is to avoid repetition - keep the date in its own group, and add alternaton between the time and the year:

```
(?P<date>\w{3}\s+\d{1,2})\s+(?:(?P<year>\d{4})|(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{2}))
```

Working example: **http://rubular.com/r/g81Kudu0dY** (without names)

Comment: What if I want to match all of them if all present?

Comment: @LeonardoRick - this question is fairly specific, it's better if you'd ask a new question with your case. In general, groups with `|` between them should work (you'll get many matches, each with one group - similar to the example here).